# Spring RESTful web service - How to get WSDL out of it?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, wsdl, webserver

I have a very simple controller class with all required annotations like `@RequestMapping` to expose it as REST services.

It works fine. The input and output model have been annotated only with `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement`. With this configuration, how do I get WSDL generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSDL is more of a SOAP concept. In spring world, it is implemented using the [Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/) framework. REST services in Spring are built using Spring MVC.

These are two separate frameworks.

TO get WSDL in Spring, you should be using the [Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/) project.

It has support for POX (Plain old XML) as well if you need that.